# Restart Hangs, Power Down and Power Up Work Fine - XP SP3

Tags: windows, windows-xp, boot, reboot

BACKGROUND

I'm Running Win XP SP3.  I can power down fine.  I can power up fine.

PROBLEM

**Restart (warmboot) hangs.**

SYMPTOMS

The HDD LED blinks on and off about twice a second.  This is a continuous blinking.  If I do not touch the system, blinking eventually stops.  The computer sits in a hung state.

Also, when I do a cold boot, the monitor gets no signal.  No BIOS info is displayed.  Signal only occurs once disk is read.

QUESTIONS

Is this indicative of a software or hardware problem?  How do I fix this problem?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"power down and power up works" indicates that it is a software related problem.
Did you install new software, twist your system or anything else?

Comment: Did not install any software or tweak system. Problem came on abruptly.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds it might be a problem with the BIOS. Have you updated the BIOS and/or firmware from the manufacturer's website? If the computer is a brand-name, then they will have it, otherwise, check with the motherboard manufacturer.

Comment: Haven't updated the BIOS.

Comment: However, see my comments below about video card BIOS.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the responses.  BTW, computer is 8 years old.  It uses an AGP video card.

**New Information:** During an F2 (enter BIOS settings) operation, which produces only DOS text, no signal present to monitor.  Swapped to an LCD monitor -- same result.  This suggests a problem with video card.  Opened case, and found video card fan frozen.  Think it's been like that for a while.  Think the 640x480 mode is shot.  When video drivers start to load, signal is presented to the display.

I've seen video cards lock a system on cold boot, but not on a warmboot with video already present.  We have 3 of these machines in the office, but no one could spare their video card for a test.

Removed HD and attached to another system as a second drive.  Drive works fine.  Am retiring the obsolete machine, and scavenging it for parts.

***Thanks for your help.  Both answers were on the right trail, (1) a software problem (2) a BIOS problem (albeit, video BIOS).***